# How to use js/jquery to access a title attribute of a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find out if there is an `<a>` tag clicked inside an `<li>` tag and only if the parent `<li>` tag has this class **myClass**. If the `<a>` has this class the page should reload.

HTML:

```
 <li id="menu-item-6076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item page-item-5840 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-top-level menu-item-top-level-2 dropdown_ul_available current-menu-item">
   --> <li id="menu-item-6047" ...>
          <a href="....de/mySite#SOME_OTHER_TEXT" title="SOME_OTHER_TEXT"  itemprop="url">
           My text
          </a>
       </li>
     <li id="menu-item-6048" ...>..</li>

 -->   <li id="menu-item-6049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item- object-custom">
         <a href="....de/mySite#SOME_TEXT" title="SOME_TEXT" itemprop="url">
          <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
          <span class="avia-menu-text">My Text</span>
         </a>
        </li>
    </li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $('.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent.current_page_parent.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-top-level.menu-item-top-level-2.active-parent-item.dropdown_ul_available.current-menu-item').on('click', 'a', function() {
        if(Boolean(window.location.href.toString().includes("xxx"))) {
            if($(this).attr('title').includes("SOME")) {
                location.hash =  "#" + 'title';
                location.reload();
            }
        }})
});
```

To make it clear I want to put the title of the clicked `<a title="some">` tag in the hash and after that I want reload but only if i am inside of this 
`<li class="myClass">`

tag with the special class.

**Background:** The page has a slider that only reacts when you click on the registers tags, the hash will be changed and the animation will be started, but I also have a menu bar with a tags that also adds that the hash value changes. From outside it works fine, but inside the page the slider doesn't react, so the page should be loaded with the new hash value.

With this latest version I get the following error while debugging:

> jQuery('.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-…n_ul_available.current-menu-item').on()
>   arguments: null, caller: null, length: 4​, name: "on", prototype: {…}
>   ​ (apply(), arguments: null, bind(), call(), caller: null
>   constructor:Function(), length: 0, name: "" toSource() toString()
>   Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance):Symbol.hasInstance : {…}

Comment: Seems like the crux of the issue may be that you're listening for the `hashchange` event which would have happened _after_ the click event.

Comment: @creativetim is there a way to check the click on demand so everytime something get clicked it triggers? because it only triggers once when i entered the page from outside

Comment: Please do not include an answer in the question itself. If you wish to add more to the existing answers, you may post a new one below.

Comment: @FCodex, yes, $(document).on('click', '.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent.current_page_parent.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-top-level.menu-item-top-level-2.active-parent-item.dropdown_ul_available.current-menu-item a', function(e) {
  // e is the browser event
  / this is the element that was clicked, your <a> tag
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already getting the value of the title in your if statement, but you are using the string `'title'` in your assignment. You need to use `$(this).attr('title')`in both places, or even better just do the following:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');

if(title.includes("SOME")) {
    location.hash =  "#" + title;
    location.reload();
}
```

Since you are using WordPress, `jQuery.noConflict()` may be in use as @charlietfl has mentioned in the comments. So you may need to replace all instances of `$` with `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    jQuery('.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent.current_page_parent.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-top-level.menu-item-top-level-2.active-parent-item.dropdown_ul_available.current-menu-item')
        .on('click', 'a', function() {
            var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');

            if(title.includes("SOME")) {
                location.hash =  "#" + title;
                location.reload();
            }
         })
});
```

You are also only applying the click event when the hash changes, you should potentionally setup the on click every time the page loads via adding when the document is ready. Keep in mind it would be ideal to swap out the `document` below with a specific container that you want to check within if possible, but with the limited HTML available I kept it simple.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('document').on('click', '.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent.current_page_parent.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-top-level.menu-item-top-level-2.active-parent-item.dropdown_ul_available.current-menu-item > a', function() {
        if(Boolean(window.location.href.toString().includes("apple-uebersicht"))) 
        {
            if(jQuery(this).attr('title').includes("iphone")) {
                location.hash =  "#" + 'title';
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: $ is not a function[Further information] testfile.js:1:13`

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library on your page?

Comment: Yes `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.xxx.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>`

Comment: `$` is added by jQuery. Have you verified that the jQuery script file is actually loading?

Comment: @FCodex Wordpress themes usually use jQuery.noConflict() so replace `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: yes as you can see its a wordpress site otherwise my tabslider wouldn*t work

Comment: @charlietfl thank you but it didn't worked my code now looks like this `var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
if(title.includes("iphone")) {
    if(window.location.href.toString().includes("apple-uebersicht")) {
        location.hash =  "#" + $(this).attr('title');
        location.reload();
    }
}
`

Comment: @FCodex You need to replace all instances of `$`. You have one still there in your comment and there are others on your `window` `on('hashchange')` and your `on('click')`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Solved**: Sorry for the confusing problem
>   description. Here is my
>   solution and thanks to @josh my and @creativetim thanks.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", 'a', function () {
    if(window.location.href.toString().includes("?=SpecialSpecial")) {
        var clickedBtnTitle = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        if (clickedBtnTitle !== undefined) {
            location.hash = "#" + clickedBtnTitle;
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad I could contribute to a solution!